# AWS SageMaker on GPU

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to train a neural network (Tensorflow) on AWS. I have some AWS credits. From my understanding AWS SageMaker is the one best for the job. I managed to load the Jupyter Lab console on SageMaker and tried to find a GPU kernel since, I know it is the best for training neural networks. However, I could not find such kernel.

Would anyone be able to help in this regard?

Comment: When you create a new jupyter notebook instance, you have to select which machine you want to use, at that time you have to specify gpu instance.
Have a look at gpu instance types here : https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/pricing/instance-types/

Other thin you can do, is start a non gpu jupyter notebook instance and write your code, and then while creating a training job, pass whatven gpu instance is required for your job.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You train models on GPU in the SageMaker ecosystem via 2 different components:

1. You can instantiate a GPU-powered **[SageMaker Notebook Instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/nbi.html)**, for example `p2.xlarge` (NVIDIA K80) or `p3.2xlarge` (NVIDIA V100). This is convenient for interactive development - you have the GPU right under your notebook and can run code on the GPU interactively and monitor the GPU via `nvidia-smi` in a terminal tab - a great development experience. However when you develop directly from a GPU-powered machine, there are times when you may not use the GPU. For example when you write code or browse some documentation. All that time you pay for a GPU that sits idle. In that regard, it may not be the most cost-effective option for your use-case.
2. Another option is to use a [**SageMaker Training Job**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/how-it-works-training.html) running on a GPU instance. This is a preferred option for training, because training metadata (data and model path, hyperparameters, cluster specification, etc) is persisted in the SageMaker metadata store, logs and metrics stored in Cloudwatch and the instance automatically shuts down itself at the end of training. Developing on a small CPU instance and launching training tasks using SageMaker Training API will help you make the most of your budget, while helping you retain metadata and artifacts of all your experiments. You can see [here a well documented TensorFlow example](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/machine-learning/using-tensorflow-eager-execution-with-amazon-sagemaker-script-mode/)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to train your model in a Sagemaker Studio notebook make sure you choose both a GPU instance type and GPU Image type:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/notebooks-available-images.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/notebooks-available-instance-types.html

For example for Tensorflow GPU:
[image]